# Angular ng-Options in recursive template

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am able to display all the data in single dropdown but I want to create another dropdown.

My JSON data looks like:

```
[
{
    field: "tenantId",
    index: true,
    isRequired: true,
    instance: "String"
},

{
    field: "channels",
    index: null
},

{
    field: "contractedProducts",
    values: [
        {
            field: "variantId",
            index: null,
            instance: "String"
        },
        {
            field: "altExtProductId",
            index: null,
            instance: "String"
        }
    },
    {
        field: "prices",
        values: [
            {
                field: "variantId",
                index: null,
                instance: "String"
            },
            {
                field: "statusId",
                index: null,
                instance: "String"
            },
            {
                field: "currencyId",
                index: null,
                isRequired: true,
                instance: "String"
            },
            {
                field: "priceTypeId",
                index: null,
                instance: "String"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Initially I will show the field values in dropdown from above JSON.
For example if I am selecting 1st field value from select dropdown.Then its ok.But if I select the one which has value field also.for eg: contractedProducts.So when I select contractedProducts then it should dynamically generate another select dropdown with all those fields which are nested inside it.!

**Edit :**

Need to generate this using only one select element in HTML. Is it possible to do it??

[image]

**Recursive HTML markup:**

```
<div class="row left">
            <div ng-repeat="condition in subcondition.conditions">
                <div class="form-inline" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                    <div ng-repeat="key in condition.keys">
                        <div class="form-group mb-left">
                            <select class="form-control" ng-model="key" ng-options="s as s.field for s in staticValues|subDocumentsFilter:key:staticValues"  ng-change="recursiveSubdocuments(key, condition.indexOf(condition));" ng-init="keys[0].propertyId" required>
                                <option value="">choose one</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <custom-fields></custom-fields>
                    <div class="form-group mb-left">
                        <button ng-click="deleteExpression(condition, $parent.subcondition.conditions)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row left">
            <div ng-repeat="subcondition in subcondition.subconditions" ng-include="'subcondtion'" ng-init="parent = $parent.$parent.subcondition"></div>
        </div>
```

**Angular Code :**

```
var _scope = {};
        $scope.arrayValue = {};
        function condition() {
                this.keys =[{propertyId:'product'}],
                this.operator = '',
                this.value = ''
        }

        function subcondition() {
                this.allany = 'all',
                this.conditions = [new condition()],
                this.subconditions = []
        }
        // $scope.expressions = myExpression;
        $scope.expressions = [new subcondition()];

        $scope.staticJson = function() {
            $http.get('http://modulus-linkup-45480.onmodulus.net/getProductSchema')
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.staticValues = data.attributes;
               //      //  var out = [];
               //      // angular.forEach($scope.staticValues, function(d){
               //      //     angular.forEach(d.fields, function(v){
               //      //       out.push({propertyId: v.field})
               //      //     })
               //      // })
               // return out;
                }).error(function(error) {});
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of ngShow to show dependent dropdown in case selected item has `values`:

```
<select 
    ng-options="item.field for item in items"
    ng-model="item"
></select>

<select 
    ng-show="item.values"
    ng-options="sub.field for sub in item.values"
    ng-model="subitem"
></select>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/C7YKTDlynlcfkrlSCvQ0?p=preview

Comment: so what does then *"when I select contractedProducts then it should dynamically generate another select dropdown with all those fields"* mean?

Comment: ignore the above comment please.Everything remains same but using only one select markup. I have also given angular and HTML code.Its recursive template.WIll generate infinitely based on json value.